# Consequences of disabling rtti?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Both g++ and clang++ have the option of disabling RTTI with the `-fno-rtti`.

What are all the consequences of doing so ?

Comment: Have you read the documents for example [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html)? Do you have questions about what it says? I don't see an obvious `clang` document but most likely it is similar to `gcc`.

Comment: most likely that you cant use `typeid` and/or `dynamic_cast`, because both of them rely on RTTI

Answer (score 5):

You should consult the documentation for GCC and Clang. Below is an excerpt from GCC's [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options):

> ```
> -fno-rtti
> ```
>
> Disable generation of information about every class with virtual functions for use by the C++ runtime type identification features
>   (`dynamic_cast` and `typeid`). If you don't  use those parts of the
>   language, you can save some space by using this flag. Note  that
>   exception handling uses the same information, but it will generate it
>   as  needed. The `dynamic_cast` operator can still be used for casts
>   that do not  require runtime type information, i.e. casts to `void*` or
>   to unambiguous base classes.

That means if you are not using `typeid()` and `dynamic_cast` then it should be okay.

Comment: I believe that you can still use typeid for when the operand is either a type or an expression whose static type is not a polymorphic type, because in those cases, typeid does not evaluate the expression and only provides the type-info of the static type of the expression (5.2.8/3), no RTTI needed, just like exception handling generates type-info statically, on demand. In many places in the standard, it makes it clear that in situations where a `typeid` or `dynamic_cast` expression is possible without RTTI, it should not use it (resolve to the static type). Those should work under `-fno-rtti`.

Answer (score 0):

Main features that use RTTI are `dynamic_cast<>` and `typeid`, so you won't be able to use them.